# Auto play not working for OWL Carousel animated plugin

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I am trying to create one page, for that i had downloaded template from [https://bootstrapthemes.co/item/tork-free-mobile-app-html-landing-page-template/][1] but as shown in it there is one own carousal which doesn't auto-play.

AUTO PLAY FUNCTION OF MY JS.

```js
function(a, b, c) {
    var d = function(b) {
        this.core = b, this.core.options = a.extend({}, d.Defaults, this.core.options), this.handlers = {
            "translated.owl.carousel refreshed.owl.carousel": a.proxy(function() {
                this.autoplay()
            }, this),
            "play.owl.autoplay": a.proxy(function(a, b, c) {
                this.play(b, c)
            }, this),
            "stop.owl.autoplay": a.proxy(function() {
                this.stop()
            }, this),
            "mouseover.owl.autoplay": a.proxy(function() {
                this.core.settings.autoplayHoverPause && this.pause()
            }, this),
            "mouseleave.owl.autoplay": a.proxy(function() {
                this.core.settings.autoplayHoverPause && this.autoplay()
            }, this)
        }, this.core.$element.on(this.handlers)
    };
    d.Defaults = {
        autoplay: !1,
        autoplayTimeout: 5e3,
        autoplayHoverPause: !1,
        autoplaySpeed: !1
    }, d.prototype.autoplay = function() {
        this.core.settings.autoplay && !this.core.state.videoPlay ? (b.clearInterval(this.interval), this.interval = b.setInterval(a.proxy(function() {
            this.play()
        }, this), this.core.settings.autoplayTimeout)) : b.clearInterval(this.interval)
    }, d.prototype.play = function() {
        return c.hidden === !0 || this.core.state.isTouch || this.core.state.isScrolling || this.core.state.isSwiping || this.core.state.inMotion ? void 0 : this.core.settings.autoplay === !1 ? void b.clearInterval(this.interval) : void this.core.next(this.core.settings.autoplaySpeed)
    }, d.prototype.stop = function() {
        b.clearInterval(this.interval)
    }, d.prototype.pause = function() {
        b.clearInterval(this.interval)
    }, d.prototype.destroy = function() {
        var a, c;
        b.clearInterval(this.interval);
        for (a in this.handlers) this.core.$element.off(a, this.handlers[a]);
        for (c in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) "function" != typeof this[c] && (this[c] = null)
    }, a.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins.autoplay = d
}(window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window, document),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 5000,
    autoPlayTimeout: 5000
    autoplayHoverPause: true
});
});
```